# How to change focus when using push menus?

Tags: jquery, menu, focus

I'm attempting to replace a drop-down menu with a push menu. Originally the drop-down was nested next to the main navigation link. When using Tab on the keyboard it worked as intended. Example:

```
<li>
  <a href="#" name="#women">WOMEN</a>          <!-- *Main Navigation -->
  <ul id="women">                              <!-- *Submenu         -->
    <li><a href="#">Women</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Women's Plus</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Petites</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

For a push menu, the HTML is structured differently. Example:

```
<ul>                                           <!-- *Main Navigation -->
  <li><a href="#" name="#women">Women</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" name="#accessories">Accessories</a></li>
</ul>

<div>                                          <!-- *Submenus        -->
  <ul id="women">
    <li><a href="#">Women</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Women's Plus</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Petites</a></li>
  </ul>

  <ul id="accessories">
    <li><a href="#">Women</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Men</a></li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

The problem I am running into is that the Tab on the keyboard misses the submenu entirely. I attempted to use `focus()` with `$(ahrefname).find('a').first().focus();` but I must be missing something since it will not work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.lp-sub-menu ul').each(function () {
    height = $(this).height();
    $(this).transition({
        y: +-+height + 'px'
    });
});

var heights = $('.lp-sub-menu > ul').map(function () {
    return $(this).height();
}).get(),
    maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, heights);

$('#top').on('click focus', 'a', function (e) {
        "use strict";
        e.preventDefault();

        var ahrefname = this.name,
            eLeft = $(this).offset().left,
            percent = 100 / $(window).width() * eLeft,
            submenuHeight = $(ahrefname).height();

        if ($(ahrefname).siblings().hasClass('active-sub-menu')) {
            $(this).parents('ul').find('a').removeClass('active-menu').find('span').css({
                'visibility': ''
            });
            $(ahrefname).siblings().transition({
                y: +-+maxHeight + 'px'
            }).delay(10).queue(function (next) {
                $(ahrefname).siblings().removeClass('active-sub-menu').css({
                    'margin-left': ''
                });
                next();
            });
            $('.lp-sub-menu').transition({
                height: +submenuHeight + 'px'
            });
            $(ahrefname).css({
                'margin-left': percent + '%'
            }).delay(4).queue(function (next) {
                $(ahrefname).addClass('active-sub-menu').transition({
                    y: +0 + 'px'
                });
                next();
            });
            $(this).addClass('active-menu').find('span').css({
                'visibility': 'visible'
            });
        } else if ($(ahrefname).hasClass('active-sub-menu')) {
            $('.lp-sub-menu').transition({
                height: +-+submenuHeight + 'px'
            });
            $(ahrefname).removeClass('active-sub-menu').transition({
                y: +0 + 'px'
            }).css({
                'margin-left': ''
            });
            $(this).removeClass('active-menu').find('span').css({
                'visibility': ''
            });;
        } else {
            $('.lp-sub-menu').transition({
                height: +submenuHeight + 'px'
            });
            $(ahrefname).find('a').first().focus();

        });
});
```

I have a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/builtbymay/wxxb4/) with it in action. Any help would be appreciated!

Update:

Thanks @hyunkeln! Focusing to the submenu worked but there was trouble with the next menu item—the submenu did not open then. I updated the function to the following...

```
$('.lp-sub-menu ul').each(function(){

    var height = $(this).height(),
        oid = $(this).attr('id');

    $(this).transition({ y: + - + height + 'px' });

    $(this).find('a:last').focusout(function(){
        $( "[name|='#"+oid+"']" ).focus();
    });

});
```

It results in the submenu closing. Tab again and the next submenu opens. Maybe that's a good thing? Not sure. Here's the latest [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/builtbymay/q3239/). (I'm curious why tabbing does not work well in jsFiddle? I have to test locally to see the results.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made out a couple of things in order to make this work, at first you need to move this line:

```
$(ahrefname).find('a').first().focus();
```

right next to this lines:

```
$(ahrefname).css({'margin-left' : percent + '%'}).delay(4).queue(function(next){
  $(ahrefname).addClass('active-sub-menu').transition({ y: + 0 + 'px'});
  next();
  //place it here!!!
});
```

So the object is focusable when you call the focus function.

The second thing is to focus the next menu when you blur the last item of the current submenu. I made it with just a few changes in you function:

```
$('.lp-sub-menu ul').each(function(){
height = $(this).height();
$(this).transition({ y: + - + height + 'px' });
    $(this).find("a:last").focusout(function(e){
        var oid = $(this).parent().parent().attr("id");
        $( "[name|='#"+oid+"']" ).parent().next().find("a").focus();

    });
});
```

And there's where I got, you can see this live in here: http://jsfiddle.net/wxxb4/6/.